# What does "netting" mean in this passage?

Tags: stock-exchanges, financing

I am not english native speaker, I am Italian.

What is the meaning of "netting" in this passage?

> **Clearing**
>
> the process of transmitting, reconciling and, in some cases,
>   confirming payment orders or security transfer instructions prior to
>   settlement, possibly including the **netting** of instructions and the
>   establishment of final positions for settlement. Sometimes the term is
>   used (imprecisely) to include settlement.

Source: A glossary of terms used in payments and settlement systems

Link: http://www.bis.org/cpmi/glossary_030301.pdf

Answer (score 6):

"netting" means to combine cash inflows and outflows (e.g. debits/credits, payments/receipts, income/expense) by subtracting the sum of all outflows from the sum of all inflows, creating one transaction.

For example, if you make two trades in one day with your broker - one to buy a security for $100 and one to sell it for $110 - rather then you sending your broker $100 and them sending you $110, the transactions are "netted" - meaning they will send you the "net" amount of $10 ($110 inflow - $100 outflow).

In a more general sense ("netting of instructions") it would mean to combine all instructions and only apply the "net" effect - e.g. one step forward, two steps back would combine to a "net" one step back.  Most likely it will apply to the exchange of money, but it could be applied more broadly.

Note that there doesn't *have* to be both inflows and outflows. You can also "net" multiple inflows (or outflows) into one transaction by just adding them all up, but *typical* business usage is to reduce the number of transactions by combining inflows and outflows.